# where can Find sqlite databases in spip?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, spip

I would like to recover the SQLite database directories in the framework spip order after applying a script that will give me the equivalent mysql but I do not know the name of the file containing the data base sqlite
  Can you help me ?

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

look in /config/ directory
There should be folder with sqlite database file